# Django orm left join return data like mysql

Tags: python, django

I have two table like this:

```py
class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = model.ChartField()

class Student(models.Model):
    name = model.ChartField()
    classroom = model.ForeignKey(to='Classroom', related_name='students')

class Score(models.Model):
    student = model.ForeignKey(to='Student', related_name='scores')
    score = model.IntegerField()
```

there has some data like this:

Classroom:

| name |
| --- |
| Classroom_A |
| Classroom_B |
| Classroom_C |

Student:

| name | classroom |
| --- | --- |
| student_1 | Classroom_A |
| student_2 | Classroom_A |
| student_3 | Classroom_B |

Score:

| student | score |
| --- | --- |
| student_1 | 70 |
| student_1 | 80 |
| student_3 | 90 |

Now I want to get the data by Django orm like this (return 4 rows data. Student's score get the max score as the student score. If the line's score is null, use 0 replace):

| Classroom_name | student_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Classroom_A | student_1 | 80 |
| Classroom_A | student_2 | 0 |
| Classroom_B | student_3 | 90 |
| Classroom_C | null | 0 |

The sql maybe like this:

```sql
-- sql1
SELECT
    classroom.name AS classname_name,
    student.`name` AS student_name,
    IF (
        t.`score` IS NULL,
        0,
        t.`score`
    ) AS `score`
FROM
    classroom
    LEFT JOIN student
        ON student.classroom = classroom.name
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            student,
            MAX(score) AS score
        FROM
            score
        GROUP BY student) AS t
        ON t.student = student.name
```

How can I write the orm?

I will use the result do some aggregate, maybe like this:

```sql
-- sql1 is the above code
select avg(score) from (sql1)
```

Comment: django is an ORM. it maps SQL table data into objects. don't fight the framework. work within it.

Comment: What's the purpose of this data, how and where are you using it?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that would get similar results as you want

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name',]


class ClassroomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = StudentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        fields = [
            'name',
            'students',
        ]
```

Now you have to serialize classrooms using ClassroomSerializer and data should look like this:

```
[
    {
    "name":"class_a",
    "students":
         [
             {"name":"student_a"},
             {"name":"student_b"},
         ]
    },
    other_classes...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I will use the data for aggregate